# using selectmenu plugin with angular

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was playing with using the selectmenu plugin with angular. It is a little trickier than the run of the mill plugins, wrapping it up as a directive does not quiet cut it because of the nested tags, but I got it to work see my plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/6u0OqFe0BaKDWa5TiyV6).

Along the way I ran into a strange problem. If you place 2 selects side by side the whole thing falls apart. You can see it for yourself - in the plank I posted just take the first select out of the surrounding div.

I am not sure is this a selectmenu problem or a general incompatibility between what and what. Any idea what's going on?

for additional explanation of the selectmenu directives check out [here](http://hill30.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-angular-way-selectmenu.html)

Comment: FYI, here's [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161028/angularjs-error-when-wrapping-jquery-plugin-in-a-directive) jQuery plugin that needed to be wrapped in a div or span.  We used a template to have the directive do the wrapping, so that the HTML could be written normally.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno what exactly is causing things to fall apart when you put two selects directly next to each other, but wrapping them in spans seems to resolve the issue.  That leads to me to believe there's a bug in the javascript that's doing the selectmenu styling.

Here's an example, forked from your plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/B5Tj9rwXaiRdLN9mwrsi?p=preview